# Backup-WDServer: How to specify encryption password

Tags: iis, powershell, msdeploy, iis-8, powershell-cmdlet

I read about the [Web Deploy Powershell Cmdlets](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/web-deploy-powershell-cmdlets), and I'd like to start using them.  Of course, the first task as I begin is to backup the current configuration state of my test webserver--and this cmdlet should do it:

```
Backup-WDServer -ConfigOnly
```

But, when I run it I get this complaint--I'm unsure how to resolve it:

```
Backup-WDServer : The property 'password' located at '/webServer/appHostConfig[@path='']/location[@path='']/section[@name='system.applicationHost/applicationPools']/applicationPools/applicationPoolDefaults/processModel' is 
marked as secure. You must specify an encryption password to archive this property.
At line:1 char:1
+ Backup-WDServer -ConfigOnly
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Backup-WDServer], DeploymentEncryptionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Web.Deployment.PowerShell.BackupServer
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had trouble finding documentation, but after spending time with IL DASM, reading more in the link provided in the question, and experimenting, I found this works:

```
Backup-WDServer -SourceSettings @{encryptPassword='password'} -ConfigOnly
```

If anyone has a link to more complete documentation I'd appreciate it--but Bing and Google didn't find much.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old thread however there is the answer:

```
Restore-WDServer -DestinationSettings @{encryptPassword='password'} -Package /path/to/the/zip/file
```

Answer (score -1):

How do you set encryptpassword for the Restore-WDServer? if you did this to backup

Backup-WDServer -SourceSettings @{encryptPassword='password'} -ConfigOnly